# why i get, Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on small project using **nuxt** **js** and **axios** and i try to put the response data in my `formFields` object but i get undefined error message in the console, since i have already declared `formFields` in data as you can see :

this is my code :

```
editCustomers (customerId, submit = false) {
  this.editMode = true
  this.customerId = customerId
  if (submit === 1) {
    // this.$Progress.start()
    this.$axios.$post('mydomain.com' + customerId + '/1', $('#add-customer').serialize()).then(function (data) {
      this.validation(data)
      // another form validation again using the helper
      this.refresh = true
    })
    // this.$Progress.finish()
  } else {
    this.$axios.$get('mydomain.com' + customerId).then(function (data) {
      this.formFields = data.customers[0]
    })
  }
}
```

my data variables :

```
data () {
return {
  laravelData: {},
  formFields: {},
  search: null,
  editMode: true,
  customerId: null,
  refresh: false
}
 }
```

as you can see i have already declared data, but when i do `this.formFields = data.customers[0]`
i get  this error message :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'formFields' of undefined
```

Comment: Likely because your code runs in strict mode where `this` in a *normal function call* is `undefined`. What do you expect `this` to refer to? Have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Every time you enter a new function the value of `this` changes. If you replace your callback functions with arrow functions the outer `this` value will be preserved. So change `function (data) {` to `data => {`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this part:

```
this.$axios.$get('mydomain.com' + customerId).then(function (data) {
  this.formFields = data.customers[0]
})
```

To this:

```
this.$axios.$get('mydomain.com' + customerId).then((data) => {
  // Now you can access your class instance
  this.formFields = data.customers[0]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `this` refers to the current target of the current scope, when using the `function` keyword to declare a function, `this` refers to the object with which the function is invoked.

The way you have written your code, `this` no longer refers to the  Vue instance, `this` refers to `undefined` (because the callback is presumably invoked without a `this` arg), try capturing `this` outside of the function and enclosing it in its closure:

```js
editCustomers (customerId, submit = false) {
  this.editMode = true
  this.customerId = customerId
  const vm = this; // vm = this = Vue instance
  if (submit === 1) {
    // this.$Progress.start()

    this.$axios.$post('mydomain.com' + customerId + '/1', $('#add-customer').serialize()).then(function (data) {
      // vm = Vue instance; this = undefined
      vm.validation(data)
      // another form validation again using the helper
      vm.refresh = true
    })
    // this.$Progress.finish()
  } else {
    this.$axios.$get('mydomain.com' + customerId).then(function (data) {
      // vm = Vue instance; this = undefined
      vm.formFields = data.customers[0]
    })
  }
}
```

ETA:
For a better understanding of this:

```js
function myName() { return this.name};
var obj = {name:'test'};
var objName = myName.bind(obj); // a new function where the `this` arg is bound to `obj`
var text = objName(); // text === 'test'
console.log(text);
```